# how to fix unsatisfiedLinkError when generating dll for JNI in windows platform using g++

Tags: windows, gcc, dll, java-native-interface, g++

I'm new to native programming. I've been trying to fix the unsatisfiedLinkError past 8-9 hours but got no result. After a lot of googling and stackoverflowing, I got sick of fixing it, I'm posting my problem here. Somebody please please help me.
I'm using g++ compiler in windows 32bit environment.
Here are the files that I've created:

Demo.java

```
class Demo 
{
    // Declaration of the native method
    public native int methodOfC(int arg1);
    /*The native keyword tells the compiler that the implementation of this method is in a native language*/
    /*Loading the library containing the implementation of the native method*/
    static 
    {
        System.out.println("Control is in Java.......going to call a C program......\n");
        System.loadLibrary("try");
        System.out.println("Congr8s no prob in CallApi.....\n");

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        //invoking the native method  

        int sendToC,getFrmC;
        if(args.length!=0) sendToC=Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        else sendToC=999;
        Demo ob1=new Demo();
        getFrmC=ob1.methodOfC(sendToC);
        System.out.println("This is in Java......\n Got "+ getFrmC +" in return from C.");
    }//end main
}//end Demo
```

Demo.h

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class Demo */

#ifndef _Included_Demo
#define _Included_Demo
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     Demo
 * Method:    methodOfC
 * Signature: (I)I
 */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_Demo_methodOfC
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jint);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

DemoImp.c

```
#include <jni.h>
#include "Demo.h"
#include <stdio.h>

//definition of methodOfC()
JNIEXPORT int JNICALL Java_Demo_methodOfC(JNIEnv* exeenv, jobject javaobj, int getFrmJava)
{
    printf("This is in the C program\n Got %d from java",getFrmJava);
    printf("\n.......Exiting frm C\n");
    return getFrmJava+1;
}
```

Here is how I compiled and run my prog.: [screenshot here](http://www.mediafire.com/download/xgdw34ux07lu2u6/native.zip)

```
C:\native>javac Demo.java

C:\native>javah -jni Demo

C:\native>g++ -c  -l"C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\include" -l"C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\include\win32" DemoImp.c

C:\native>g++ -shared DemoImp.o -o try.dll

C:\native>java Demo 1234

Control is in Java.......going to call a C program......

Congr8s no prob in CallApi.....

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Demo.methodOfC(I)I
        at Demo.methodOfC(Native Method)
        at Demo.main(Demo.java:23)

C:\native>
```

I've already **added "C:\native" in my system path** variable.
I've uploaded all my **files in mediafire**. Here's the link [native.zip](http://www.mediafire.com/download/xgdw34ux07lu2u6/native.zip)
If possible please tell me how can I make 64bit version of dll. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed out the package name in the DemoImp.c  file.

The naming convention for C function is Java_{package_and_classname}_{function_name}(JNI arguments). The dot in package name shall be replaced by underscore.